# Objective C Code to convert NSDate into ticks format

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I want to know how to convert NSDate into ticks format.

```
NSDate *date = NSDate *conversionDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"29-03-2018 00:00:00"];
```

And the result should be

> Ticks = 636579950240000000

Comment: Well there is `NSDate` method: `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` which is quite useful in your case. Then a second is just 10 millions ticks, so there is a simple calculation. `NSTimeInterval ts = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];` To get ticks, multiply by 10 000 000.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a NSTimeInterval (aka a double) with

```
NSTimeInterval ti = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

That would be the number of seconds since Epoch (GMT)

A tick is 100 nanosecondes, so you got to multiply by 10^7.